# Extract string between chars in SQL Server strings

Tags: sql-server, string, char, nvarchar

Can some one kindly suggest ways by which I can extract `0459` and `0460` from a string like `(&0459&/&0460&)*100` in a SQL Server table?

I should be able to pull out two strings sandwiched between two pair of ampersands.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the  &/& is also a sandwiched string. How would you avoid that ?

Comment: you can do it using PatIndex and SubString, once you decide what rules to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain there are always two pair of ampersands you may extract the two strings like this

```
declare @s varchar(max) = '(&0459&/&0460&)*100'

declare @first int = charindex('&', @s)
declare @second int = charindex('&', @s, @first+1)
declare @third int = charindex('&', @s, @second+1)
declare @fourth int = charindex('&', @s, @third+1)

select substring(@s, @first+1, @second-@first-1)
select substring(@s, @third+1, @fourth-@third-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution will grap 1st and 3th value between '&'

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
     SELECT t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)') v,
     rn = row_number() over (order by (select 1))-1
     FROM (
         SELECT x = CAST('<t>' + 
               REPLACE('(&0459&/&0460&)*100', '&', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
     ) a
     CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)
)
SELECT v FROM CTE
WHERE rn in (1,3)
```

Result:

```
0459
0460
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion, I am trying your answer as well, but its a bit more complicated.